# Firebase dependency conflict Found 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4', with 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0'

Tags: android, firebase, qr-code

my application include QR Scanner and Generator but when i add 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0' library it conflect with 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4' library

[here my Gradle dependences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKkzr.png)

plus it shows me an error .. 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.8.0.

Comment: okay did u update the version, as said in the error?

Comment: Please update the same version of play services vision library which is  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.4' in your gradle.

Comment: it asks me to install Repository and when i download them, it appear an error "Couldn't find dependency com.google.android.gms:google-services:11.0.4"

Answer (score 1):

Always try to use same version of APIs when you are dealing with google APIs:

**If you are using Android Studio 3.0 you can use both compile and  implementation**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.4'
```

**If you are using Android Studio version below 3.0 use compile**

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.4'
```

Comment: @Kyrillos happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
```